# Trying to find what this type of problem is called - predicting output based on weighted set

Tags: probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling, means

Given a set of numbers such as this:

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20

The numbers in the set are "magnetized/weighted" (sorry for lack of better term). Given an input number, it should always output a number that already exists in the set - with a higher likelihood of being output as that number based on frequency in the set (lots of 1's in above example), and how close the input is to it.

Example input/outputs:

- 6 -> 5
- 7.5 -> 10
- 15 -> 20
- 2 -> 1

Does anyone know what this type of problem is called? Or how I could develop a formula for it? I've been trying to search for it, but haven't had any luck finding what this type of problem is.

Comment: It is not at all **explicitly** clear in what way the decision is made for deciding which direction to go.  Of course, part of your question is "*how can i develop a formula for it*" so I don't expect you to have perfectly decided how it works.  As it stands, I would expect it to be (*in pseudocode*) take an input $x$, find the number closest to it in the set that is greater or equal and the number closest to it that is less or equal, call them $a$ and $b$ respectively, and their respective frequencies $n_a$ and $n_b$.  Compare $n_a/(|x-a|)$ and $n_b/(|x-b|)$, output $a$ or $b$ based on higher

Comment: Of course, you could come up with different formulae that have similar effect, for example instead comparing $n_a/(|x-a|)^2$ and $n_b/(|x-b|)^2$ (*closer in line to actual equations in physics for gravity, $F_{\text{grav}} = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$*), or some other way of interpreting what you want.

Comment: I was envisioning that all the numbers would have some pull, so the number  7 wouldn't just be pulled by 5 and 10, but also by the 1s and 20s as well to a lesser degree. Maybe given enough frequency of the other numbers, it might even skip the nearest number entirely and go that of higher frequency/pull.

Comment: Well.. again, it is your brainchild... so however you decide to write the formula is what the formula happens to be.  There is no one single correct answer here.

Comment: Similar to @JMoravitz suggestion you could have that the probability of an output y, given input x, is proportional to $n_x/(x-y)^2$. Or do you prefer for it to be a deterministic function? Without context it's hard to know what might best suit your needs.